# Generated group by sql query does not make sense

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework core for mysql, and i've been running a complex linq query which i'm trying to optimise. 
I turned on logging in the mysql server to view the resulting queries from the linq queries. 
Oddly, none of it made sense as my complex query that joined 5 tables and performed multiple group bys, where, and order by clause was registered in the logs as 5 separate select all columns from table statements.

So, I tried a simple group by statement for one table. The resulting sql log produced "Select all_columns from table_name order by groupbyid".

Can anyone explain what happened here?

Thanks in advance.

More info as requested:

Sql query:

var queryCommand = (from p in _context.TableExtract                                                                               group p by p.tableExtractPersonId);
                    queryCommand.ToList();

Resulting mysql log after:
SELECT .... [very long list of column names]
FROM `TableExtract` AS `p`
ORDER BY `p`.`tableExtractPersonId`

I've tried two different entity framework libraries: MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore(v8.0.17) and Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql (v2.2.20) with the same results. I've tried .net core 3.0 and also received the same results. I'm going to try .net standard next.

Comment: could you add a sample code on what you have done? your linq query, table structure, entities?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found it:
var queryCommand = (from p in _context.TableExtract group p by p.tableExtractPersonIdinto g select g.Key)

Forces linq to evaluate as a SQL group by. Otherwise apparently it does it's own thing with the group by.